# Converting Class Component to Functional Component With Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I tried to convert the class component code below :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import api from '../api'

import styled from 'styled-components'

import 'react-table/react-table.css'

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    padding: 0 40px 40px 40px;
`

const Update = styled.div`  
    color: #ef9b0f;
    cursor: pointer;
`

const Delete = styled.div`
    color: #ff0000;
    cursor: pointer;
`

class UpdateVoter extends Component {
    updateUser = event => {
        event.preventDefault()

        window.location.href = `/voters/update/${this.props.id}`
    }

    render() {
        return <Update onClick={this.updateUser}>Update</Update>
    }
}

class DeleteVoter extends Component {
    deleteUser = event => {
        event.preventDefault()

        if (
            window.confirm(
                `Do you want to delete this voter ${this.props.id} permanently?`,
            )
        ) {
            api.deleteVoterById(this.props.id)
            window.location.reload()
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <Delete onClick={this.deleteUser}>Delete</Delete>
    }
}

class VotersList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            voters: [],
            columns: [],
            isLoading: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true })

        await api.getAllVoters().then(voters => {
            this.setState({
                voters: voters.data.data,
                isLoading: false,
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        //const { voters, isLoading } = this.state

        const columns = [
            {
                Header: 'ID',
                accessor: '_id',
                filterable: true,
            },
            {
                Header: 'No KK',
                accessor: 'nkk',
                filterable: true,
            },
            {
                Header: 'NIK',
                accessor: 'nik',
                filterable: true,
            },
            {
                Header: 'Nama',
                accessor: 'nama',
                filterable: true,
            },
            {
                Header: 'Alamat',
                accessor: 'alamat',
                filterable: true,
            },
            {
                Header: '',
                accessor: '',
                Cell: function(props) {
                    return (
                        <span>
                            <DeleteVoter id={props.original._id} />
                        </span>
                    )
                },
            },
            {
                Header: '',
                accessor: '',
                Cell: function(props) {
                    return (
                        <span>
                            <UpdateVoter id={props.original._id} />
                        </span>
                    )
                },
            },
        ]

        let showTable = true
        if (!this.state.voters.length) {
            showTable = false
        }

        return (
            <Wrapper>
                {showTable && (
                    <ReactTable
                        data={this.state.voters}
                        columns={columns}
                        loading={this.state.isLoading}
                        defaultPageSize={10}
                        showPageSizeOptions={true}
                        minRows={0}
                    />
                )}
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
}

export default VotersList
```

to this functional component code :

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import api from '../api'

import styled from 'styled-components'

import 'react-table/react-table.css'

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    padding: 0 40px 40px 40px;
`

const Update = styled.div`
    color: #ef9b0f;
    cursor: pointer;
`

const Delete = styled.div`
    color: #ff0000;
    cursor: pointer;
`

function UpdateVoter(props) {
    const updateUser = event => {
        event.preventDefault()

        window.location.href = `/voters/update/${props.id}`
    }

    
        return <Update onClick={updateUser}>Update</Update>

}

function DeleteVoter(props) {
    const deleteUser = event => {
        event.preventDefault()

        if (
            window.confirm(
                `Do tou want to delete this voter ${props.id} permanently?`,
            )
        ) {
            api.deleteVoterById(props.id)
            window.location.reload()
        }
    }

        return <Delete onClick={deleteUser}>Delete</Delete>
  
}

function VotersList(props) {
    const [voters, setVoters] = useState ({voters: []})
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState ({isLoading: false})

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            setIsLoading(true)
            return (setVoters(await api.getAllVoters()))
        }
        console.log(fetchData())
    }, [])

        const columns = [
            {
                Header: 'ID',
                accessor: '_id',
            },
            {
                Header: 'No KK',
                accessor: 'nkk',
            },
            {
                Header: 'NIK',
                accessor: 'nik',
            },
            {
                Header: 'Nama',
                accessor: 'nama',
            },
            {
                Header: 'Alamat',
                accessor: 'alamat',
            },
            {
                Header: '',
                accessor: '',
                Cell: function(props) {
                    return (
                        <span>
                            <DeleteVoter id={props.original._id} />
                        </span>
                    )
                },
            },
            {
                Header: '',
                accessor: '',
                Cell: function(props) {
                    return (
                        <span>
                            <UpdateVoter id={props.original._id} />
                        </span>
                    )
                },
            },
        ]

        let showTable = true
        if (!voters.length) {
            showTable = false
        }

        return (
            <Wrapper>
                {showTable && (
                    <ReactTable
                        data={voters}
                        columns={columns}
                        loading={isLoading}
                        defaultPageSize={10}
                        showPageSizeOptions={true}
                        minRows={0}
                    />
                )}
            </Wrapper>
        )
    
}

export default VotersList
```

But, I got the blank result. The table is not displayed. I tried to `console.log(fetchData())` inside `useEffect` function, and I got this result `Promise {<pending>}` printed in the console. What does it mean? And why is the table not displayed as it should be? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does it mean?

`Promise {<pending>}` is telling you that the result of the function is a promise that has not yet resolved. [An `async` function will return a Promise when invoked without `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function);

If you want to view the contents of your network request you should `console.log` within your `fetchData` function.

> And why is the table not displayed as it should be?

I think this is occurring because you are not setting the `getAllVoters` result correctly.

In your original code you set the state variable `voters` to `data.data` from the API result, whereas in the refactored code you simple set it to the result with:

```
setVoters(await api.getAllVoters())
```

You could fix this by changing it to:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        setIsLoading(true)
        const voters = await api.getAllVoters();
        setVoters(voters.data.data)
    }

    fetchData()
}, [])
```

---

It is also worth mentioning that you are using `useState` incorrectly.

You are using it like this:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState({ isLoading: false });
```

Whereas it should be used like this:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
```

At the moment you are setting the variable `isLoading` to this object: `{isLoading: false}` whereas you simply want to set it to false.

This isn't causing you problems at the moment as you are immediately changing the value to true with `setIsLoading(true)`, however, it will probably cause bugs down the line.

The same is true for `useState ({voters: []})`.

Comment: I've tried this, but still got the same result as previously.

Comment: What is the result if you `console.log` the result of your `getAllVoters` request inside the async function?

Comment: Hi. I just add this line of code `setIsLoading(false)` into the last line inside the async function and it works perfect now. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `setVoter` from `fetchVoter` function inside `useEffect`, that's why console is printing a promise.

You should try like this

```
async function fetchData() {
  const data = await api.getAllVoters()
  return data
}

async handleDataFetch() {
   setIsLoading(true)
   const data = await fetchData()
   setVoters(data)
   setIsLoading(false)
}

useEffect(() => {
  handleDataFetch()
}, [])
```

Comment: I've tried this and unfortunately still got the same result (empty result).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're not using `useEffect` hook effectively. There are few problems I've seen in your code one of them is using `async` with a function(which is correct) but the rule of `async-await` is that when you have an `async` function you got to `await` wherever you call it.
Also the good practice is to put your api logic outside `useEffect`in a separate function.
There's one more issue I found in your code is your `isLoading` state is initialized as an object but then in your `fetctData` function you're set-ting it as a bool value which is wrong. You can simply initialized it to be `true` and set it to `false` after data has been fetched
So your above component code of `VotersList` will look something like this

```
function VotersList(props) {
    const [voters, setVoters] = useState({voters: []})
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let allVoters = await api.getAllVoters();
      setVoters(allVoters);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }

    useEffect(async () => {
        let allVoters = await api.getAllVoters();
        setVoters(allVoters);
    }, [])
    // OR
    /*
    useEffect(async () => {
        await fetchData();
    }, [])
    */




        const columns = [
            {
                Header: 'ID',
                accessor: '_id',
            },
            {
                Header: 'No KK',
                accessor: 'nkk',
            },
            {
                Header: 'NIK',
                accessor: 'nik',
            },
            {
                Header: 'Nama',
                accessor: 'nama',
            },
            {
                Header: 'Alamat',
                accessor: 'alamat',
            },
            {
                Header: '',
                accessor: '',
                Cell: function(props) {
                    return (
                        <span>
                            <DeleteVoter id={props.original._id} />
                        </span>
                    )
                },
            },
            {
                Header: '',
                accessor: '',
                Cell: function(props) {
                    return (
                        <span>
                            <UpdateVoter id={props.original._id} />
                        </span>
                    )
                },
            },
        ]

        let showTable = true
        if (!voters.length) {
            showTable = false
        }

        return (
            <Wrapper>
                {showTable && (
                    <ReactTable
                        data={voters}
                        columns={columns}
                        loading={isLoading}
                        defaultPageSize={10}
                        showPageSizeOptions={true}
                        minRows={0}
                    />
                )}
            </Wrapper>
        )
    
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but got this error : 
`Warning: An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.

It looks like you wrote useEffect(async () => ...) or returned a Promise. Instead, write the async function inside your effect and call it immediately:`